# sorting input files on the basis of number of observations

Tags: r

I have multiple files with different number of observations in a directory and need to sort the files on the basis of number of observations and save them like the sequence file1, file2, file3.... and so on. 
For example, consider i have 4 files with number of observations 5, 6, 3, 2 and named as abc, ikl, hj, op respectively. Now, after sorting and renaming files should be saved in the directory in the following manner.
file1 is the file with number of observations 2, file2 should be the file be the file with number of observation 3, file3 with 5 and file4 with 6. Is there any way i can do this in R?

```
 abc           ikl           nj                 op

1  2  3       20 1  2        76 43 56        233 123 56
4  5  6       10 5  8        12 11 10        564 15  45
7  8  9       3 77  9        4  2  1
10 11 12      12 8 90
13 14 15      5  6  8 
              2  1  7
```

After renaming:

```
file1          file2          file3          file4

233 123 56     76 43 56       1  2  3       20 1 2
564 15 45      12 11 10       4  5  6       10 5 8
                4  2  1       7  8  9       3 77 9
                              10 11 12     12 8 90
                              13 14 15      5 6 8
                                            2 1 7
```

please note that abc, ikl, hj, op,file1, file2, file3, file4 are the names of the files.

Comment: Could you give a data example? Thank you!

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I have added one example. Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of code but it gets the job done:

```
# Crate some data frames
abc <- data.frame(matrix(0, 5, 3))
ikl <- data.frame(matrix(1, 6, 3))
nj <- data.frame(matrix(2, 3, 3))
op <- data.frame(matrix(3, 2, 3))

# This is where your code starts
# put them in a list
l <- list(abc, ikl, nj, op)

# find the number of observations for each data.frame
l1 <- sapply(l, function(x) dim(x)[1])


for(i in 1:length(l)){
  assign(paste0("file", i), l[order(l1)][[i]])
}
```